# Реляционная База Данных Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, crud

У меня есть такие таблицы:

```
| id         | subject       |
------------------------------
| 1          | Математика    |
| 2          | Химия         |
| 3          | Физика        |


| id         | text          | created_at | subject_id |
--------------------------------------------------------
| 1          | Lorem ipsum.. | 2017 20 07 | 3          |
| 2          | 2 Lorem ipsum | 2017 20 09 | 2          |
| 3          | some text     | 2017 21 11 | 3          |
```

---

Как мне реализовать это с помощью **миграций** и сделать их **реляционными**?

А также, этот список я планирую заменить следующим образом:

```html
<select class="form-control">
      <option>Алгебра</option>
      <option>Геометрія</option>
      <option>Українська література</option>
      <option>Зарубіжна література</option>
      <option>Економіка</option>
      <option>Біологія</option>
      <option>Хімія</option>
      <option>Географія</option>
      <option>Інформатика</option>
      <option>Інформаційні технології</option>
      <option>Історія України</option>
      <option>Всесвітня історія</option>
      <option>Художня культура</option>
      <option>Фізкультура</option>
      <option>Правознавство</option>
      <option>Англійська мова</option>
      <option>Українська мова</option>
</select>
```

Вот так:

```html
@foreach($subs as $sub)
<option>{{ $sub->subject }}</option>
<!-- $sub->subject тут хранится имя предмета -->
@endforeach
```

### НО!

Как мне потом **обработать** этот участок кода при записи в **БД?**
И как мне позже в пути `../{id}/edit` сделать выбраным селект, по `id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделать таблицы реляционными вам прийдется всё равно прописывая соответствующие отношения в моделях. 
Для первой:

```
public function dataTable()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\DataTable', subject_id);
    }
```

Для второй ( куда записываете )

```
public function subject()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\subject', subject_id);
}
```

Вся запись у Вас ведется в вторую таблицу с использованием id из первой.

```
 @foreach
    ($subs as $sub)
        <option value= {{$sub->id}} >{{ $sub->subject }}</option>
        <!-- $sub->subject тут хранится имя предмета -->
 @endforeach
```

В форме action должен ссылатся на роут который будет принимать этот запрос `{!! Form::open(['route' => 'post.store']) !!} @include('post._form') {!! Form::close()!!}`

Ну а в контроллере обрабатывайте чемто вида :

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
           $projects = new dataTable();
           $projects->create($$request->all());
           return redirect()->route('posts');
    }
```

Comment: Отлично, а как мне записывать в БД значение из `option`?

Comment: Создайте Route который будет принимать POST запрос с страницы где находится форма на которой находится этот option, ну а дальше в контроллере записывайте как вам удобнее. В форме action должен ссылатся на роут который будет принимать этот запрос {!! Form::open(['route' => 'post.store']) !!}
        @include('post._form')
    {!! Form::close()!!} а в контроллере обрабатывайте чем то вида : public function store(Post $postModel, Request $request)
{
       $postModel->create($request->all());
       return redirect()->route('posts');
}

Comment: ах да, действительно `$request->all()` здесь же передается все..

Comment: Можете более детально расписать функцию `public function dataTable()` и `public function subject()`. Где я должен что писать, если у меня есть модель **Task** и **Subject**

Comment: Это определение отношений моделей. Подробнее о них можете почитать в документации https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships